How Can We Meet Herr Klöcking's Call to Community?
In his recent post about upcoming moderator elections, Moderator Philip Klöcking wrote:

New input and energy for shaping and developing a proper community would be most welcome, since any attempt to form something more than individuals debating issues to death in comment threads failed so far.

My question is, is it even possible to shape and develop a "proper" community, as Philip asks, and through the lens of a collective action problem, what collective action does it entail? When I first started participating, trying to find how I could contribute to this board as a community member, to learn from those who knew more than me (which is most), Philip and I had a conversation about whether this place was a Cathedral or a Bazaar. Several other long-time contributors such as Bumble, Chris Sunami, Paul Ross, and other's responded.
While, my sometimes argumentative nature gets the better of me, I'd be lying to say that in a very real sense, participating here is an extension of Schiller's call for coming together. (That would be Friedrich and not Peter Schilling, btw.) I'm willing to continue to collaborate to build a "proper" community, but I can't subsume myself to the body politic if there is no clear body politic, no organizing principles other than a libertarian forum styled on the only principle that outside of the basic tenets of the board (don't be a jerk, don't spam, don't revenge downvote, etc.) there are no actual values or collective action.
According to WP:

A community is a social unit (a group of living things) with a shared socially significant characteristic, such as place, set of norms, culture, religion, values, customs, or identity.

Community organizing is a collective action problem, and therefore without collective values, collective plans, and collective action, communities cannot be brought into existence. Is the will even here?
So, I'll test the water with what I perceive to be literally the smartest group of people I've been privileged to have discourse with: By what practical steps would a global and disparate rag-tag group of philosophy amateurs and experts go about coordinating and building such principles to rise to meet Philip's call for a "proper" community?
I'm more than willing to process more flags, build HTML content, cultivate BeefText libraries, but it has to be in service of something bigger than myself.
So, Philip, you can count on me if you want to organize a "proper" community, also "wem der große Wurf gelungen Eines Freundes Freund zu sein".

@JuliusHamilton I'm tagging you because if you're going to drag me into taking responsibility through a nomination, I'm dragging you into laying out a vision of what a "proper" community is.

@ScottRowe I'm tagging you because few on this board has added more to the laid-back and humorous laden comments that makes the board feel like a community.

@KristianBerry I'm tagging you because few seem explicitly manifest a deep commitment to a profound exploration of morality and dialectic in the original spirit of the pre-Socratics.

Finding shared norms and values for what constitutes a good question and what constitues a good answer.
Why is this so important?

(a) such norms govern the most fundamental actions users have
(b) such norms are key to creation of a quality repo, ie the stack exchange vision, a vision that is unique to this community in virtue of being on, well, stack.
(c) good questions and good answers attract users who share this vision as well as repel low quality content (which kills a community).

Problem:

(i) ppl don't agree on these.
(ii) even when people agree, they don't act- not enough people downvote,high rep users in certain specialties with answers of markedly lower quality outside of these specialities, questions with almost no research effort shown that would surely be thrown out on another sub, etc...

It might be interesting to have people find what they believe to be good questions and good answers, post and upvote them in the meta, and attempt to actually act as a community on this. Or we might actually create such a guide, and enforce it. Of course, there is the tyranny of the democracy, but a good moderator might also help with this.

It seems that Meta could be used for actual democratic expression and coordination, but that isn't a thing at the current point, and it seems either discouraged by the current culture, or at a minimum not encouraged by it.

Yes, I agree that meta might play such a role

@JD That is what Meta is supposed to be used for, actually

The biggest obstacle I see to this board becoming a lively community is that there are very limited formats for positive dialog.
Discussion is expressly prohibited in comments.
Discussion boards -- are live for only a limited time, then close forever.
The dialog on discussions -- tends to advance toward non-communicative parallel absolutism.
Here are several thoughts, that could promote community:

Open up the content of questions here on Meta.  More lighthearted/chatty topics would create a more friendly environment, at least for the small number of us show show up here.  The 404 thread is a great start in this direction.

Create more than just the one permanent discussion board -- instead create multiple boards, with sub-themes:  Logic, philosophy of mind, god/religion, Physicalism and its alternatives, morality, free willing and determinism -- this is a short off the cuff option list.  Maybe just these boards will do the job, to draw discussion.  OR -- maybe we need a more stringent rule to make them friendly    Perhaps all new postings would need to be "huh, think about that" type posts, of links to discoveries or new publications?   Then replies to each of these cannot reject the ideas presented, but only discuss them with pluses and negatives, and negatives not allowed to exceed pluses?


OK, two free-form ideas.  maybe neither will work.

+1 for the 1st para

Yeah, the Q&A format does certainly impose a certain type of tyranny that thephilosophyforum.com doesn't have a problem with. The notion that users should have a venue for conversation moderated on tone and not content would be a tremendous benefit for drawing more activity.

This is just a hodgepodge of small but not meritless ideas I have had in considering feasible improvements to Philosophy SE. (The number of unfeasible good ideas is very large.)

I don’t know if anyone has been too successful in giving a rubric or criteria for what constitutes a “good philosophy question/answer”, and after trying a bit to organize that effort myself, I now think we should eschew any goals that are too complex. A realistic goal would be the slow, hard-won aim of say, changing or adding one single option to the pop-up menu of close reasons when you flag a post. It turns out that these are indeed customizable. Politics SE has quite a different set of close reasons. So, one small change with actually huge ramifications would maybe be surveying the crowd to see if anyone wants to suggest a conservative change to the close rules.

I personally have lately been exploring having a good LLM like Claude 3.5 Sonnet rephrase questions and answers “in the style of a philosophy exam” on the high school, undergraduate and graduate level. Instead of the onerous task of analyzing what factors define a “good answer”, I’ve been using this to give me a good example of what a pedagogically sound philosophy question can look like.

If possible, I would strongly support more software-structured encouragement to take the time to edit other people’s posts in the review queue. I often prefer to edit other people’s posts to make them better than to close them and encourage them to write better posts themselves. A lot of our posts could become really high quality if people collaborated on editing, refining and sourcing them. I would support a review queue explicitly focused on editing posts, not just closing them.

Anything we can do to attract academics here would be great… maybe it’s as little as setting off a feedback loop or something. With more academic contributors, hopefully other academics would want to use the site more, to ask or answer their own questions. We should look to Math Overflow for guidance, and even ask the creators of that site how we can raise the bar for post quality and attract legitimate experts.

There has been some discussion about the chat rooms being too quiet - why don’t we focus on that? I don’t know a simple way to do this, but if we look to apps like Discord one can have an idea of a much more engaging chat platform that lets people split off into threads, channels, share media, etc. I think chat is so quiet because the software doesn’t have a lot of good features.


Other than that, I’m satisfied with the site as-is. It’s important to not try to control or structure the system excessively. We just need a minimal base system whose emergent behavior is determined by the users. So I am advocating small, targeted, conservative modifications to the “base system”.
I tried to start a Zulip server, I haven’t been active in promoting it, but it’s a chat platform used by quite a few academic communities. We can use it in the interim to promote “collective action”: working together to research things, work on goals, etc. https://plato.zulipchat.com/
If anyone wants to work on getting more discussion going over there, then request some user permissions / admin credentials at juliushamilton100@gmail.com. Or just join and make your first post. Thanks.
